# Porque marca erro en el xml

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo

Estoy añadiendo una pestaña en mi modelo de odoo pero a la hora de actualizar marca un error de un campo inexistente pero revisando el dogi si existe tanto en el modelo en python como en el xml

Adjunto codigo python:

```
    class RecursoBascula(models.Model):

    _name = "recurso_bascula"

    Ancho = fields.Integer()
    Alto = fields.Integer()
    Volumen = fields.Integer()
    Peso_Bruto = fields.Integer()
    Descripcion = fields.Char()
    Palletizado = fields.Selection(selection=[
        ('SI', 'SI'),
        ('NO', 'NO'),
    ])
    Emplayado = fields.Selection(selection=[
        ('SI', 'SI'),
        ('NO', 'NO'),
    ])
    Flejado = fields.Selection(selection=[
        ('SI', 'SI'),
        ('NO', 'NO'),
    ])
    Sello = fields.Selection(selection=[
        ('SI', 'SI'),
        ('NO', 'NO'),
    ])
```

Asi es como lo tengo en el codigo de los modelos

y asi lo tengo en el xml

```
     <notebook>
              <page >

                      <tree editable="bottom">
                          <field name="Ancho"/>
                          <field name="Alto"/>
                          <field name="Volumen"/>
                          <field name="Peso_bruto"/>
                          <field name="Descripcion"/>
                          <field name="Palletizado" required="1"/>
                          <field name="Emplayado" required="1"/>
                          <field name="Flejado" required="1"/>
                          <field name="Sello" required="1"/>
                      </tree>
              </page>
          </notebook>
```

Asi es como lo tengo estrcuturado no se si mi estrutura este mal pero cuando lo actualizo en la terminal manda un error que el campo ancho no existe en el modelo que tendria que hacer para que no mande ese error

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error que se muestra?

Comment: Revisa la indentación...

Comment: se supone que esta bien identado

Comment: no se si tenga que ver que tengo dos modelos en el mismo archivo python los puse asi porque para ambos la vista xml es la misma

Comment: Es posible tener dos modelos en el mismo achivo. Si no es problema de permisos, seguramente odoo no reinstalo el modulo de manera automatica. Toca probar de nuevo actualizar directamente en las aplicaciones o volver a instalar si no funciona.